# How to change icon colors in KitKat?

Tags: android, searchview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have troubles to change icon colors in KitKat inside the search view.

When I click on search icon in my toolbar it becomes like this

[image]

After I click on this lens toolbar transforms like this

[image]

Could you suggest me any way to make those icons white in API 19?
I can make close icon lighter with this code

```
  int idSearchCloseIcon = searchView.getContext()
      .getResources()
      .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
  ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(idSearchCloseIcon);
  searchCloseIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

When I put `search_mag_icon` instead `search_close_btn` nothing happens at all.

Here is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/toolbar_menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/toolbar_menu_contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_mail_white_48dp">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/toolbar_menu_about">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: can you add your menu.xml which contains the search menu?

Comment: added `menu.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer to my question myself. It's not really proper solution but in works on api 19 and probably it will save a lot of time for someone.

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` I added this part to avoid the view that you see on image 1 in a question

```
 searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
 searchView.setFocusable(true);
 searchView.setIconified(false);
 searchView.clearFocus();
 searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Than in the same `onCreateOptionsMenu` I'm looking for edit text to apply some styling. I set hint programmatically and this removes this lens icon.

```
 // EditText styling
 int idSearchTextView = searchView.getContext()
     .getResources()
     .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
 final EditText editText = searchView.findViewById(idSearchTextView);
 if (editText != null) {
     editText.setTextColor(getResources()
          .getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor));                
     setCursorColor(editText,getResources()
          .getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor));
     // this is done to remove icon from a hint!!!!
     editText.setHint(getString(R.string.home_search_input_hint));
 }
```

In this case after you click on search button you'll see expanded toolbar like this

[image]

But if you click  close icon you'll be back to

[image]

To avoid this I override on clock event of close button in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
 int idSearchCloseIcon = searchView.getContext()
    .getResources()
    .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
 ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(idSearchCloseIcon);
 // add this listener to avoid return on view with lens icon
 searchCloseIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         if(editText != null){
             editText.setText("");
         }
     }
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImageView searchHintIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(idSearchCloseIcon);

Drawable newIcon = searchView.getDrawable();

if (newIcon != null) {
    newIcon.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE,
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    searchHintIcon.setDrawable(newIcon);
}
```

Comment: ` menuItem.setIcon(newIcon);` I need to set icon color not to a menu item but to a hint of EditText for search

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy from my code.  Updated it to be the ImageView and correct method

Comment: This changes the close button color. But for 'lens' icon I try search_mag_icon and this doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to change the search lens image :

```
int idSearchLens = searchView.getContext()
                .getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
        ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(idSearchLens);
        searchCloseIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me it doesn't work. For now only that works is 'editText.setHint("");'

Comment: Yeah I see this code change the search lens icon not the hint icon.
I thought that you want to change just the color of the search lens.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Drawable.setDrawableTint(context: Context, @ColorRes colorRes: Int) {
    val color = context.getColorByRes(colorRes)
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(this.mutate(), color)
    } else {
        val color = context.getColorByRes(colorRes)
        val drawable = this.mutate().apply {
            setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color)
    }
}
```